# Copy from browser paste to netbeans not working

Tags: copy, paste

Copy from browser paste to netbeans not working. How could this be happen?
When I try to paste notepad, it is working, but when try to netbeans it is not working? I am in shock

Answer (score 26):

Try to make an empty copy (Ctrl+C without selection) within Netbeans and then try again to perform copying from browser or another application.
It works for me after many solutions I tried.

This [bug report](https://netbeans.org/nonav/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=205697)
also suggests adding

```
-J-Dnetbeans.slow.system.clipboard.hack=false
```

to the `netbeans_default_options` in `netbeans.conf`, but it did not work for me.

Comment: is it invalid for the parameter?

Comment: @gumuruh I don't understand the question? Anyway, just try to make an empty copy within the Netbeans to reset the clipboard, that works for me.

Answer (score 19):

This Problem is known for over 10 years now and still not fixed.

See https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88161

Workaround: Restart the IDE.

Comment: empty copy (Ctrl+C without selection) worked on Netbeans 15

Answer (score 16):

It looks like the NetBeans IDE assumes that what a developer does with other applications (clipboard operations) is not relevant to NB.  The only time that NB does not apply this assumption is when the clipboard is empty.  The NB clipboard must first be emptied by cutting or copying nothing (similar to previously posted answers).  There is no menu item; there is no shortcut to clear the NB clipboard.

This problem still applies to NB 12.0 as of 2021/5/18.

Comment: Still as of nov 11, 2021, but that trick of cutting empty works well!

Comment: On Win11 JDK17 Netbeans 13, not selecting anything copies the whole line.

Comment: still on NetBeans IDE 15 ...

Comment: @TugalsanKarabacak it needs to be a blank line

Answer (score 7):

Selecting text and dragging into the Netbeans still works if you are lazy to restart.

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing the same problem. If you use cut (ctrl+x) and paste (ctrl+v) instead of copy (ctrol+c) it works.

Comment: Nope it did not work for me Win11 JDK17 Netbeans 13

Comment: This worked for me. ctrl-X in Maven, then Ctrl-V in other app. The return to Maven and Ctrl-Z to restore the text.

Answer (score -1):

Stop NB and run NB with Administrator privilege, it works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

1. Press Windows+R
2. type *%appdata%*
3. Go to local folder in AppData (you might be in Roaming folder go back one)
4. Go to Netbeans folder
5. And delete Cache folder.